# What is the reason behind the disappearance of TextView?

Tags: android-studio, encoding, textview, android-linearlayout, android-cardview

When adding `LinearLayout`, the `TextView`disappears from the design

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:cardview="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:padding="20dp">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
 android:id="@+id/cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp">
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="328dp"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:background="@drawable/customborder"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/sendbad">
    </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="زيت السندباد × 1 لتر "
            android:textSize="17dp"
            android:textColor="#000000">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="الكرتونة = 12 زجاجة"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textColor="#000000">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"
            android:layout_margin="3dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="السعر =185 ج.م"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:textColor="#000000">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView>
      </LinearLayout>
   </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Don't use dp sizes in your design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Constraint layout or in linear layout use code like below

`<TextView
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="41dp"/>`